# Why am I getting a No Method Error?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and am still having trouble parsing error messages. My method takes a string in this form:
"8, 2, 1, 6; 3, 1, 3, 2; 6, 4, 2, 7; 7, 3, 2, 4"

My goal is to split each set (offset by ;) into a subarray of an array and convert each value in the subarrays to an integer. Then, I need to print the second value in each subarray. I am getting stuck on the last part. Here is the code:

```
@input = "8, 2, 1, 6; 3, 1, 3, 2; 6, 4, 2, 7; 7, 3, 2, 4"
@array = []

def splitter
  @input.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
  @array = @input.split(';').map { |group| group.split(',') }
  @array.map! { |subarray| subarray.map! {|v| v.to_i} }
  @array.each { |e| print e(1) }
  puts ''
end

splitter
```

and here is the error message:

```
`block in splitter': undefined method `e' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I'm wondering if I'm not using the right form for an array of arrays.

Comment: `e[1]` instead of `e(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply mlovic. That's a rookie mistake for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "8, 2, 1, 6; 3, 1, 3, 2; 6, 4, 2, 7; 7, 3, 2, 4"

str.split(';').map { |e| e.split(',').map(&:to_i) }
#⇒ [[8, 2, 1, 6], [3, 1, 3, 2], [6, 4, 2, 7], [7, 3, 2, 4]]
```